# intel(r) q45/q43 express chipset driver

Tags: 12.04, drivers, intel-graphics

--

**i use ubuntu 12.04** ,and i want to install **driver** for **intel(r) q45/q43 express chipset**

intel(r) q45/q43 express chipset work fine on my windows xp and i use dual boot ubuntu 12.04 and windows xp

---

btw in my windows it say i have 2 intel(r) q45/q43 express chipset in the device Manager, and i never install drivers on ubuntu .....  can you anyone help me??

---

i want to install driver because  when i go to system settings/details 
then i go to  graphics  i found this

- driver unknown
- experience standard

Comment: Why do you think you need to install the driver?

Comment: @Mitch it's a common Windows migration paradigm - users always assume that you have to install drivers on Linux because they're so used to doing it on Windows, I originally self-compiled apps when I started out in Linux back in '07 because the concept of a package management system was alien to me.

Comment: @CraigWatson That's why I wanted to know, if there was anything wrong with the installation:)

Comment: i want to try to play word of tanks on  ubuntu if i can play on ubuntu i will stop use windows xp

Comment: @Mitch i want to install driver because when i go to system settings/details then i go to graphics i found this

driver unknown
experience standard

Answer (score 0):

You won't have to install drivers for most devices because unlike Windows, Ubuntu ships with a comprehensive set of drivers built right into the operating system.

Is there anything actually *wrong* with your PC? Is the display resolution incorrect, do you have bad colour depth, can you not enable 3D effects?

If the answer to all of the above questions is no, you don't have to worry about installing drivers.

Answer (score 0):

To download the graphics driver for your system, download the [Intel Linux Graphics Installer version 1.0.2](https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/2013/intelr-linux-graphics-installer-version-1.0.2).  Make sure that you choose the right file, either the 32bit or 64bit Ubuntu driver.